# Can't write unknown attribute for a has_many through source with another has_many to same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-many-through, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am receiving the error:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `[:account_id, :list_id]`
```

Models:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts_lists
  has_many :subscriptions, -> {uniq}, :through => :accounts_lists, source: :list
  has_many :lists, foreign_key: 'creator_id'
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts_lists
  has_many :subscribers, -> {uniq}, :through => :accounts_lists, source: :account
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'Account'
end

class AccountsList < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = [:account_id, :list_id]
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :list
end
```

I am trying to run the seed method and add a list to an account in the following commands:

```
a = Account.create(email: 'email', password: 'secret', password_confirmation: 'secret')
list1 = List.create(creator: a, list_type: music, name: "a's list 1")
a.subscriptions << list1
```

I have changed the name of the typical `account.lists` for the many-to-many join because of the nature of the application. An Account can have many lists of which it is subscribed, as well as many lists that it was the creator of.

I believe that from the way that the error is worded, it is having trouble finding the right association to use for the addition of the `List` onto the `subscriptions` collection of `Account`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after reading all of the documentation and looking at my needs and the configuration options of the `has_many :through` and `has_and_belongs_to_many`, I realized that I don't really need the `has_many :through` due to the nature of the joins, and since the `has_and_belongs_to_many`(habtm for short) has all of the configuation options that I needed to define *exactly* what I needed the join to be like. I decided to try out that option. Below is the working code for any future googlers out there that are having the same problem.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :subscriptions, -> {uniq}, class_name: 'List', join_table: 'accounts_lists', foreign_key: 'subscription_id', association_foreign_key: 'subscriber_id'
    has_many :lists, foreign_key: 'creator_id'
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :subscribers, -> {uniq}, class_name: 'Account', join_table: 'accounts_lists', foreign_key: 'subscriber_id', association_foreign_key: 'subscription_id'
    belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'Account', foreign_key: 'creator_id'
end
```

And just to point out another interesting join scenario I had was the following:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :parents, -> {uniq}, class_name: 'List', join_table: 'lists_lists', foreign_key: 'parent_id', association_foreign_key: 'child_id'
    has_and_belongs_to_many :children, -> {uniq}, class_name: 'List', join_table: 'lists_lists', foreign_key: 'child_id', association_foreign_key: 'parent_id'
end
```

This is a many-to-many where basically a `List` can have `Lists` which in turn can have `Lists` which can have more `Lists` etc, etc, etc...

Hope this helps others with this problem in the future... though.... If anyone knows how to do this with a `has_many :through` I would still love to know if this is possible using that type of join.